# Reference for automorphic form via representation theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I don't know anything about automorphic form but I heard it is related to representation theory and number theory. I am interested in both fields, so I would like to know if there is any introductory textbook or online paper that starts from the very basic.

I only know a basic of finite group representation theory and algebraic number theory (not class field theory.)
So the more elementary, the better.

Comment: Do you know the usual modular forms on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), \Gamma_0(N),\Gamma_1(N)$, the space $S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ and the Hecke operators ? Looking at your activity, it seems you don't care so much of analysis, modular forms and L-functions, and that you are interested much more in algebraic theory. So what do you want to do with automorphic forms ? The Galois representation ?

Comment: @user1952009 I might have studied some modular form when I studied elliptic curves but I am not familiar with it. I don't have a specific reason to study automorphic form but L-function, Galois representation sound good and I want to learn them. So I am open to both analytic or algebraic.

Comment: Personally I have studied some Fourier and complex analysis, then some books on algebraic number theory and $\zeta(s)$, after what modular forms and general L-functions with Diamond and Shurman's book (well not the second part : algebraic and Galois representation) with the help of [Paul Garrett's notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/) and Kaczorowski's work on the Selberg class, and now I'm beginning to look at automorphic forms.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot involved in automorphic forms, and a lot of aspects to come at it from.  It is good to learn modular forms or elliptic curves first, though most accounts of modular forms don't make the representation theory aspect evident.  (The advantage of elliptic curves is that you will probably see the representation theory sooner.)

My suggestion is to read some surveys of what it is all about first.  I have a [short overview](http://www.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/papers/mfs.pdf), and a list of [open-access resources](http://www.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/autreps/).  The list includes some course notes and a bunch of survey papers.  Gelbart's "elementary introduction" on that list is a classic.  Don't expect to understand all the details, but you can get a rough overview this way.  Then you can try to figure out what you want to learn in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to learn something about classical modular forms first. A very approachable text for this is Diamond and Shurman's A First Introduction to Modular Forms.

Afterwards, perhaps the most friendly automorphic forms and representation theory text is Bump's Automorphic Forms and Representations. However, you mention that you are not familiar with class field theory, and this is going to give you some trouble. The reason is that the simplest case of automorphic representations corresponds strongly with the ideas from class field theory (and in fact, one might consider the Langlands Program a vast extension of class field theory).